# listview does not updates

Tags: android, android-listview

I am expirience wierd situation because my list view updates only once.
The idia is following, i want to download posts from web, which are located on page 3 and page 5 and show both of them on listview. However, List view shows posts only from page 3. MEanwhile, log shows that all poast are downloded and stored in `addList`.

So the problem - `objects from second itteration are not shown in listview`. Help me please to fix this issue.

```
public class MyAddActivateActivity extends ErrorActivity implements
        AddActivateInterface {
    // All static variables

    // XML node keys
    View footer;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "not_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "not_title";
    Context context;
    public static final String KEY_PHOTO = "not_photo";
    public final static String KEY_PRICE = "not_price";
    public final static String KEY_DATE = "not_date";
    public final static String KEY_DATE_TILL = "not_date_till";
    private int not_source = 3;
    JSONObject test = null;
    ListView list;
    MyAddActivateAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> addList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.aadd_my_add_list_to_activate);
        footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loading_view, null);
        addList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ImageView back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ChooserActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
//      if (intent != null) {
//          not_source = intent.getExtras().getInt("not_source");
//      }

        GAdds g = new GAdds();
        g.execute(1, not_source);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter = new MyAddActivateAdapter(this, addList);
        list.addFooterView(footer);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String add_id = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_my_add_id)).getText().toString();
                add_id = add_id.substring(4);
                Log.d("ADD_ID", add_id);
                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddToCheckActivity.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                UILApplication.advert.setId(add_id);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    private void emptyAlertSender() {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Ничего не найдено");
        alertDialog.setMessage("У вас нет неактивных объявлений.");
        alertDialog.setButton("на главную",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                ChooserActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    class GAdds extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // addList.clear();
            Log.d("backgraund", "backgraund");
            UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
            return u.getAdds(params[0] + "", params[1] + "");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("postexecute", "postexecute");
            footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            JSONArray tArr = null;
            if (result != null) {

                try {
                    tArr = result.getJSONArray("notices");

                    for (int i = 0; i < tArr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject a = null;
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        a = (JSONObject) tArr.get(i);
                        if (a.getInt("not_status") == 0) {
                            int premium = a.getInt("not_premium");
                            int up = a.getInt("not_up");
                            if (premium == 1 && up == 1) {
                                map.put("status", R.drawable.vip + "");
                            } else if (premium == 1) {
                                map.put("status", R.drawable.prem + "");
                            } else if (premium != 1 && up == 1) {
                                map.put("status", R.drawable.up + "");
                            } else {
                                map.put("status", 0 + "");
                            }

                            map.put(KEY_ID, "ID: " + a.getString(KEY_ID));
                            map.put(KEY_TITLE, a.getString(KEY_TITLE));
                            map.put(KEY_PRICE,
                                    "Цена: " + a.getString(KEY_PRICE) + " грн.");
                            map.put(KEY_PHOTO, a.getString(KEY_PHOTO));
                            map.put(KEY_DATE,
                                    "Создано: " + a.getString(KEY_DATE));
                            map.put(KEY_DATE_TILL,
                                    "Действительно до: "
                                            + a.getString(KEY_DATE_TILL));
                            map.put("check", "false");
                            Log.d("MyAddList", "map was populated");

                        }

                        if (map.size() > 0)

                        {
                            addList.add(map);
                            Log.d("MyAddList", "addlist was populated");

                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (UILApplication.login != 2) {
                    UILApplication.login = 3;

                }

                onCreateDialog(LOST_CONNECTION).show();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            if (not_source == 3) {
                not_source = 5;
                GAdds task = new GAdds();
                task.execute(1, 5);

            }
            if (not_source == 5) {
                Log.d("ID", m.get(KEY_ID));

                if (addList.size() == 0) {
                    emptyAlertSender();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addAct(View v) {
        AddActivate aAct = new AddActivate(this);
        aAct.execute(addList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAddActivate(JSONObject result) {
        if (result != null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

adapter

```
public class MyAddActivateAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Row> rows;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private Activity activity;

    public MyAddActivateAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        Log.d("mediaadapter", "listcreation: " + data.size());
        rows = new ArrayList<Row>();// member variable
        this.data = data;
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return RowType.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        rows.clear();
        for (HashMap<String, String> addvert : data) {

            rows.add(new MyAddActivateRow((LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), addvert));
            Log.d("MyActivateAdapter", "update " + data.size());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return rows.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return rows.get(position).getView(convertView);
    }
}
```

Comment: please make your question understandable.

Comment: not_source is only 3 once, then it is changed to 5 and never changed back meaning it won't update again

Comment: I guess if you are calling `GAdds` over and over, before you call it again (After the entire update process) change not_source back to 5, its a bit hard to understand what you want specifically sorry

Comment: you are right. IT should make only two runs to get result for 3 and for 5, then stop and show both results in listview. However on result from 3 is shown

Comment: The idia is following, i want to download posts from web, which are located on page 3 and page 5 and show both of them on listview

Comment: @Yarh Are you getting this log printed in your logcat "Log.d("MyAddList", "addlist was populated");" ? If yes, how many times?

Comment: 8 times, also i add log in the end and saw   - all kies are uniq. should i provide other classes?

Comment: Try logging the size of arraylist

Comment: Can you post your adapter? Make sure that getCount method from adapter returns the correct size, you might need to Override it and set to return the size of your addList.

Comment: size is correct - 8 as it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you aren't calling the super class of notifyDataSetChanged(), maybe try

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    rows.clear();
    for (HashMap<String, String> addvert : data) {

        rows.add(new MyAddActivateRow((LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), addvert));
        Log.d("MyActivateAdapter", "update " + data.size());
    }
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```